# Elasticsearch script sort on nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following type in elasticsearch

```
"hotel" : {
   "magicScore" : 1
   "rooms" : [
        {
       "type" : "single",
       "magicScore" : 1
        }, 
        {
        "type" : "double",
        "magicScore" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

where rooms is of type nested. I would like to sort using a scripted sort, for example

```
 "sort" : [ {
    "_script" : {
      "script" : "return doc['magicScore'].value + doc['rooms.magicScore'].value",
       "params" :  ,
      "type" : "number",
      "reverse" : true
    }
  } ]
```

This does not work because rooms are nested objects, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticsearch allows [Script Based Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) and [Sorting within nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting), more over you can mix both approaches together.  You could try something like:

```
"sort" : [ {
   "_script" : {
      "nested": {
         "path": "rooms"
      },
      "script" : "return doc['magicScore'].value + doc['rooms.magicScore'].value",
      "params" :  ,
      "type" : "number",
      "reverse" : true
}}]
```

Once the `nested path` is specified, elasticsearch would lookup the terms of referred nested documents if those are indexed, so it would be possible to refer to them through the `doc` map.  This would avoid the need to load the whole `_source`.

Comment: I'm facing similar problem but while trying to sort using the script, I'm getting `RequestError: RequestError(400, u'x_content_parse_exception', u'[1:29] [_script] failed to parse field [type]')`

Comment: This answer absolutely deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields):

> doc[...] notation only allows for simple valued fields (can’t return
>   a json object from it) and makes sense only on non-analyzed or single
>   term based fields.

You would need to use access it via the [_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_source_field) field

Something on these lines:

```
   "sort": [
      {
         "_script": {
            "script": "m=doc['magicScore'].value;for(obj in _source.rooms){ m += obj.magicScore;};return m;",
            "type": "number",
            "reverse": true
         }
      }
   ]
```

Comment: hey, sorry for taking a while to reply. What you wrote works and ill accept it as answer. I had a huge performance hit because my documents are large. I ended up using a function_score query in java it would be something like QueryBuilders
                .nestedQuery("rooms",
                        QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(filterBuilder,
                                ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction()
                                        .param("values", values))
                ).scoreMode("max")

Comment: The next step for a future refactoring would be to use a bool query so i can access both the fields from the parent object and the nested object. The functionscorequery inside the nestedquery can only see fields from the nested documents. I had to put the magicScore field inside the nested documents for the whole thing to work